# Selenium webdriver link query using chrome driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hi i am unable to click on a link using chrome driver in selenium. Can some one help me ? I used :

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("text").click()
```

But didn't work

Comment: please share the html source code

Comment: @BeforeTest

 public void OpenBrowser() {

  driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.newtours.demoaut.com/");
  driver.manage().window().maximize();

 }

 @Test(priority = 1, enabled = false)

 public void VerifyRegister() throws InterruptedException {

  // Find Register Link and click on it
  Thread.sleep(3000);
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("REGISTER")).click();

Comment: Copied the code snippet above. Note that i am a novice in selenium and is trying to learn it. And its at the following section i get unable to locate element exception in eclipse. driver.findElement(By.linkText("REGISTER")).click();

Answer (score 0):

Try the following CssSelector, i just tried it and it works:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='mercuryregister.php']")).click()
```

Hope this unblocks you

Comment: Thanks Moe. I tried the method you mentioned. But i am still getting an error.Copied the screenshot for your reference below,

Comment: Thats odd, why dont you just use: driver.get("http://www.newtours.demoaut.com/mercuryregister.php") and see if that works. also the screenshot is missing

Comment: Thanks Moe,, Finally i was able to crack it by doing a trial and error. it worked by using dynamic xpath. I used driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='REGISTER']")).click(); . And it worked.